# Get Rotation of an Edit Bone

Tags: python, bones, transforms

How can I get the rotation of an edit bone (or just the raw bone, but not the pose bone)?

Or if it's not directly possible, what's the formula for getting the rotation of a line between two points in 3D space? I know there must be one but I've been banging my head for hours today and didn't get anywhere.

[image]